# Stuck in an Array pickle

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have an array of numbers called `CM`, which I would then like to calculate **EACH array item** as the percentage of another number, lets call it `totalOfCM` (The sum of all the numbers in array `CM`).

Is there a way that I can loop through that array and put the result into another array without having to do the calculation manually each time?

This is what I am doing at the moment, but I am sure it can be easier:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var CM = [0,5,2,0,0,0];

    var totalOfCM = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < CM.length; i++) {
        totalOfCM += CM[i] << 0;
    }

    var percentage1CM = parseInt((CM[0] / totalOfCM) * 100)
    var percentage2CM = parseInt((CM[1] / totalOfCM) * 100)
    var percentage3CM = parseInt((CM[2] / totalOfCM) * 100)
    var percentage4CM = parseInt((CM[3] / totalOfCM) * 100)
    var percentage5CM = parseInt((CM[4] / totalOfCM) * 100)
    var percentage6CM = parseInt((CM[5] / totalOfCM) * 100)

    alert(percentage1CM);
    alert(percentage2CM);
    alert(percentage3CM);
    alert(percentage4CM);
    alert(percentage5CM);
    alert(percentage6CM);
});
```

My current Jquery first tallys up the `SUM` of that array, but then I am manually working out the percentage of each array item :( HEre is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zb5htf8f/) of what I am doing.

Please let me know if I need to do more explaining?

Could someone please guide me in the right direction?

Thanks a mill,

Mike

Comment: any particular reason why you're doing a `<< 0` there?

Comment: none what so ever :) I got that off another SO thread. I'm new to Jqeury. haha

Comment: There is no use of `<< 0`. Do you want this http://jsfiddle.net/svv6c9gc/

Comment: The only jQuery in the question is the document ready event handler. Please re-tag your question.

Comment: nothing clear about `<< 0`, `FYI` case value have precision part that will be trim.

Comment: Anyway, thanks to those who answered me. I didn't really Ask, What is wrong with the `<<0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a simple **for** loop.

```
var percentage = []; //Declare an array
for (var i = 0; i < CM.length; i++) {
  percentage.push(parseInt((CM[i] / totalOfCM) * 100)); //Add calculated percentage
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/svv6c9gc/1/)

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
var CM = [0,5,2,0,0,0];

// calculate sum first
var sum = CM.reduce(function(prev, current) {
    return prev + current;
}, 0);

var percentages = CM.map(function(value) {
    return value * 100 / sum;
});
```

Afterwards, `percentages` is an array with the percentage corresponding to each value of `CM`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [$.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map),

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var CM = [0, 5, 2, 0, 0, 0];
    var totalOfCM = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < CM.length; i++) {
        totalOfCM += CM[i] << 0;
    }
    var arr=$(CM).map(function(i,v){
        return v*100/totalOfCM;
    }).get();
    console.log(arr);// your final array
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zb5htf8f/1/)**